# How can I get my loop to print out 20 numbers per line?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to use a single for loop to print out to print every 5th number from 105 - 500 and have 20 numbers per line. So far I have been able to get the code to print 105 - 500, but I don't know how to get it to print 20 numbers per line. Can someone help, please?

**The program should output:**

```
105 110 115 120 125 130 135 140 145 150 155 160 165 170 175 180 185 190 195 200
205 210 215 220 225 230 235 240 245 250 255 260 265 270 275 280 285 290 295 300
305 310 315 320 325 330 335 340 345 350 355 360 365 370 375 380 385 390 395 400
405 410 415 420 425 430 435 440 445 450 455 460 465 470 475 480 485 490 495 500
```

**Here's my code so far:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int i, j;
    
    for(i = 105; i <= 500; i+=5)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    
}
```

I tried adding a second for loop, but I'm not allowed to do that for this program.

Comment: `int linebreak = 0;` ... `if (++linebreak == 20) { std::cout << "\n"; linebreak = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to conditionally print a newline character if `i` is divisible by `100`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 105; i <= 500; i += 5 )
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";

        if ( i % 100 == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }      
    }
}
```

This program prints the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 100; i <= 495; i += 5 )
    {
        std::cout << i + 5 << " ";

        if ( i % 20 == 0 )
        {
            std::cout << '\n';
        }      
    }
}
```